# Using a single powerful computer with multiple users

Tags: hardware-virtualization

Let's say a high-end PC e.g. 24+ cores, 128+ GB RAM, NVMe SSD.

I have a team of developers (5-10 people) and want them to use the same computer with multiple VMs. Is this doable and feasible, since software development doesn't usually require extreme resources?

Please feel free to share your experiences if you've ever done something similar.

Comment: Before there were PCs, i.e. *personal* computers, mainframe computers shared their resources using timeshare connections.

Comment: There are many options. A common option is to install Windows Server, which allows multiple simultaneous logins, and then each person uses Remote Desktop to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can!

You will need to select remote desktop Client and Server apps which use the same protocols, so each developer can network into the powerful 'server' machine from their desktop 'client' PC, so take a look at this [list of Remote Desktop Client and Server apps for multiple OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).

However, even the best of Client and Server apps result in a disappointing desktop experience, with as-if-I-was-on-the Moon keyboard response and remote session mouse pointers which significantly drag behind the mouse pointers on the client.

The place where I work (to remain nameless) has hundreds of developers at my location alone, and they don't do that, instead opting for traditional desktops for their developers.

Answer (score 2):

Read on the Multipoint Server: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/multipoint-services/introducing-multipoint-services

> There are several ways users can access their sessions. One way is by
>   remoting into the server using the remote desktop apps with any
>   device. Another way is through physical stations... attached to the
>   MultiPoint server

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RDP Wrapper Library project](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/releases) it enables you to run multiple user logins into the same windows machine just like you would on windows server. Here is a more [descriptive installation](http://woshub.com/how-to-allow-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-10/) of the wrapper. RDP on a local LAN is just as good to use as on your own machine. As long as the machine that is handling multiple users has the enough ram to host the applications this would be adequate for most needs as you only need to install all the software once on the machine and users can have their login sessions persisted if set up to do so.